# How to set date for an inline Datepicker in jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How to set date for an inline `Datepicker` in jqueryUI?

Comment: How are you calling date picker in your code???

Comment: default lnk http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: $('.datepicker-single').datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );

Comment: Like you would set the date on any datepicker, by using setDate like it says in the docs.

Comment: Hello akshay, i want to set a custom date for it, let say i have to give next month(june) 5th 2013, how would i do this for inline datepicker

Comment: @TechQ did you check my answer

Comment: hi, adeneo, can you please provide the example for inline datepicker to set the date

Comment: Sure -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tXyLn/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much adeneo, you made my day, i was working for this issue more than 5 hours. thank you once again budy....!!!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When initializing a datepicker, you'd use the `defaultDate` option:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    defaultDate: '01/26/2014'
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tXyLn/3/)

when changing the date later, you'd use `setDate` method:

```
$("#date").datepicker();
  // more code
$("#date").datepicker('setDate', '01/26/2014');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tXyLn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set multiple dates as well by using this:

```
    allBookings = []

    _.each(Session.get('thisGuide').bookings,function(e){
        allBookings.push(moment(e).format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
    })

    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDates',allBookings)
```

Comment: have you tested this, I need something like this, but it is not working.