# How to change JQuery datepicker default date/month to a particular month

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have a textbox where I am using JQuery datepicker and I want the calendar to display the default month as September.

I have tried many ways but nothing seemed to be working, it displays the default date as current date.

Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtArrivalDate" CssClass="span3 inline uneditable-input" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

And in the .js file, I have tried these things:

```
var days = new Date();

days.setMonth(days.getMonth() + 2);
//$("#txtArrivalDate").datepicker('setDate', days); // try 1

$('#txtArrivalDate').datepicker(
    {
       $( "#txtArrivalDate" ).datepicker('setDate',days); //try 2
    });
```

Comment: Here you can find everything you need: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Straight to the point: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Answer (score 0):

This was answered here: [How to set date for an inline Datepicker in jquery UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733395/how-to-setdate-for-inline-datepicker-in-jquery-ui) . 
Just set defaultDate, or inizialize the datepicker first (.datepicker()), and then call the setDate function.

Answer (score 0):

This will set the picker to the current day and year, but in September.

```
var today = new Date();
var newDate = "09/" + today.getDate() + "/" + today.getFullYear();

$("#txtArrivalDate").datepicker({
    defaultDate: newDate
});
```