# Datepicker on a div, with default value or value from querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

So, I'm using datepicker on a div element (so that the calender is always on).
I have a default value, but I have cases where I want to start with a value from query string.

I tried to put value inside the div, it is just displayed on the div and not on the datepicker :/

Partial html is as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" id="datepickerPage">
  <div id="dateDepart" class="datepicker"></div>
</div>
```

The javascript for init the datepicker: (it happens on a transfer page):

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#datepickerPage", function () {
    initDatePickers();
});


 function initDatePickers(){
 $("#dateDepart").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    yearRange: "-0:+1",
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
    //some function
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedDate, inst) {

       //some function
    },
});
```

on the regular pageload I am loading a date from query string and putting in the DIV:

```
//singleParam is the isolated date query string
 singleParam = ("from=19%2f02%2f2015").split("=");
 $("#dateDepart").html(unescape(singleParam[1]));
```

What I get with this code is the date 19/2/2015 inside the div that is turing to a datepicker, but the datepicker stays with the default date (+1week)... (11/02/2015)

Help??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733395/how-to-setdate-for-inline-datepicker-in-jquery-ui

Comment: thanks,
But the datepicker is not initialized yet (on pageload), only after.

I can change it if I must, I prefer not to.

I want the same behavior as datapicker on Input, so if it has value, it puts that value as the selected date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually my solution was changing the defaultDate to a param:

```
var defaultDateParam = "+1w";
```

If i get a query param i replace the defaultDateParam to that value.

So my init now looks like this:

```
$("#dateDepart").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  yearRange: "-0:+1",
  changeYear: true,
  defaultDate: defaultDateParam,
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
    //some function
  },
  onSelect: function (selectedDate, inst) {

     //some function
  },
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use [setDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) method after page loads?

Comment: on page load the datepicker does not exist yet, only after the user enters the page #datepickerPage, I can do the setDate after, but I wanted the entire query handle to happen on the main page load...